# Laravel Backpack Image Field Error: 1406 Data too long for column

Tags: php, laravel, crud, laravel-backpack

Can't figure out why CRUD is trying to store the image binary into the database, instead of the uploaded file's name.

**Model**

```
public function setImageAttribute($value)
{
    $attribute_name = "image_wheel";
    $disk = "wheel";
    $destination_path = "wheel_png";

    // if the image was erased
    if ($value==null) {
        // delete the image from disk
        \Storage::disk($disk_wheel)->delete($this->{$image_wheel});
        \Storage::disk($disk_vehicle)->delete($this->{$image_vehicle});

        // set null in the database column
        $this->attributes[$image_wheel] = null;
        $this->attributes[$image_vehicle] = null;
    }

    // if a base64 was sent, store it in the db
    if (starts_with($value, 'data:image'))
    {
        // 0. Make the image
        $image = \Image::make($value);
        // 1. Generate a filename.
        $filename = md5($value.time()).'.jpg';
        // 2. Store the image on disk.
        \Storage::disk($disk)->put($destination_path.'/'.$filename, $image->stream());
        // 3. Save the path to the database
        $this->attributes[$attribute_name] = $destination_path.'/'.$filename;
    }
}
```

**Error Message**

> Next Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[22001]: 
>   String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'image_wheel' at row 1 
>   (SQL: insert into `wheels` (`name`, `part_no`, `alias`, `series_id`, `sizes`, `image_wheel`, `image_vehicle`, `description`, `order`, `status`, `featured`, `-wheel_image_id`, `-wheel_tags`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (, , , , , data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAMCAgICAgMCAgIDAwMDBAYEBAQEBAgGBgUGCQgKCgkICQkKDA8MCgsOCwkJDRENDg8QEBEQCgwSExIQEw8QEBD/
>   ...........

Comment: what is the definition of this `image_wheel` field

Comment: @Arafath  
Shouldn't it just be storing the md5($value.time()).'.jpg' name though instead of the binary for the image?

Comment: @cvassios did you find the solution ? I am facing same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uahmed's answer led me to the correct answer

When defining a mutator, according to Laravel's documentation

> To define a mutator, define a setFooAttribute method on your model where Foo is the "studly" cased name of the column you wish to access.

So in my case the function name should be

`public function setImageWheelAttribute($value)`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the function name. The function name should have the field name . Like in your example it is

```
 $attribute_name = "image_wheel";
```

so the function name should be

```
public function setImage_wheelAttribute($value)
```

This will solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to change your `image_wheel` to `text`. You're probably hitting the max length of the current data type of that field.

Comment: Shouldn't it just be storing the  `md5($value.time()).'.jpg'` name though instead of the binary for the image?